# Flutter push new screen inside same modal bottom sheet

Tags: flutter

In my app's `LoginScreen()` I have an option to log in using a one-time password. If a user selects that option a modal bottom sheet is shown where they input their phone number. When they press a button the phone number is sent to a new modal bottom sheet where they can confirm the code. The issue with this is that it ends up having two modal bottom sheets stacked on top of each other and if a user wants to go back to the log-in screen they have to dismiss both instead of just one. How can I do something like `Navigator.of(context).push()` inside the modal bottom sheet?

Here's what I currently have...

`LoginScreen`>`PhoneAuthScreen`:

```
                      showBarModalBottomSheet(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) => PhoneAuthScreen());
```

`PhoneAuthScreen`>`OTPValidationScreen`:

```
                      showBarModalBottomSheet(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) =>
                              OTPValidationScreen(phoneNumber: phone));
```

Comment: you could pop the first dialog after operation is complete and display the second, this way the user only needs to pop the one which is visible(second dialog in your case)

Comment: From what i see in the description, if you don't want two modelsheet you can use pageview and add those two pages in it. And control based on the actions.

Comment: That was my first thought but since I have a variable (the phone number) being passed to the second modal bottom sheet from the first one, that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Modal bottom sheets usually don't have a `Scaffold`. That's why when a `Navigator.pop(context)` is triggered, it's going to clear all the sheets on its way.

I suggest you to make the `PhoneAuthScreen` a normal screen with `Scaffold`. Not a modal bottom sheet.

Then use the `OTPValidationScreen` as a sheet like you do.

Comment: Actually, both of the screens have a `Scaffold` and are built as two regular `StatefulWidget`. The only difference is that I use a method from a package to present them as modal bottom sheets instead of full screens.

Comment: `That's why when a Navigator.pop(context) is triggered, it's going to clear all the sheets on its way`

> Not sure if I'm interpreting this correctly, but `Navigator.pop(context)` just clears the last entry in the navigation stack, which means only the `top` bottom sheet is retracted when multiple sheets are stacked

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the issue was that I could not use `Navigator.of(context).pop` before showing the next modal bottom sheet because a variable was being passed to the new one. Here was my solution:

1. Make the phone number a static string so it could be accessed all the time. This made it possible for me to leave the screen and still pass the phone number to the next one.
2. Change the code from this:

```
                      showBarModalBottomSheet(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) =>
                              OTPValidationScreen(phoneNumber: _phoneNumber));
```

to this:

```
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      showBarModalBottomSheet(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) =>
                              OTPValidationScreen(phoneNumber: _phoneNumber));
```